# Install python modules from Collab to Jupyter

Tags: python, pip

How may I install all the packages or modules that are within my Google Collab storage to my new Jupyter environment. I can view a list of the installed packages on Google Collab with the following command.

```
!pip freeze
```

However there are north of 100 modules that I'd like to install. Therefore I would like to avoid manually "pip" installing each module with the Jupyter environment as much as possible.

Comment: Note that your "Jupyter" environment is a bit of a misnomer. Jupyter has "kernels" for python environments. Make sure you install to the python environment of the kernel you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is

1. Write down the packages in `requirements.txt` (e.g. in your GitHub project)
2. Change the dir to your project folder & install packages

`!cd my-project && pip install -r requirements.txt`

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood what you're asking, you should be able to do

```
!pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

and then, to install them all in one go,

```
!pip install -r requirements.txt
```